# Scroll to the selected row of a datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatable

I would like my datatable to automatically scroll to the row selected by the user. My goal is the selected row to be displayed on top of the table. Below is my attempt with a MRE :

```
# libs
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

# data
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100,
  Name = LETTERS[1:100],
  Value = rnorm(100)
)

# app
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("table"),
    tags$script(HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('scrollToSelectedRow', function(selectedRow) {",
      "  table.row(selectedRow - 1).scrollTo(false);",
      "});"
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data,
        selection = 'single',
        options = list(
          paging = FALSE
        )
      )
    })
    
    # observer
    observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
      selectedRow <- input$table_rows_selected
      session$sendCustomMessage("scrollToSelectedRow", selectedRow)
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code:

1. You need to switch on the `Scroller` extension `extensions = "Scroller"`
2. You need to define a reference to `table`: `const table = $('#table table').DataTable();`
3. `scrollTo` does (for whatever reason) not work properly, thus, you need to replace it by `.node.scrollIntoView()`

Having said all this, here's the complete code:

```r
# libs
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

# data
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100,
  Name = LETTERS[1:100],
  Value = rnorm(100)
)

# app
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("table"),
    tags$script(HTML(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('scrollToSelectedRow', function(selectedRow) {",
      "  const table = $('#table table').DataTable();",
      "  table.row(selectedRow - 1).node().scrollIntoView();",
      "});"
    ))
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        data,
        selection = 'single',
        options = list(
          paging = FALSE
        ),
        extensions = 'Scroller'
      )
    })
    
    # observer
    observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
      selectedRow <- input$table_rows_selected
      session$sendCustomMessage("scrollToSelectedRow", selectedRow)
    })
  }
)
```